# Negatable options in perl

Tags: perl, command-line-arguments, getopt, getopt-long

I have a negatable option defined as **top!**.

When a command uses this option, say : **command_name -top**, prints a warning to the user

Code snippet for it is as follows :

```
if ($args{top}) { print "Warning"; }
```

But, when a command uses a negated option, say : **command_name -notop**, it does not print the same warning to the user.

Is there a way to get same warning for both the cases?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can determine if your option (in either form) has been used on the command line or not.
Since you are using a hash for your options, you can check if the option [exists](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/exists):

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use Getopt::Long qw(GetOptions);

my %args;
GetOptions(\%args, qw(top!));

print "Warning\n" if exists $args{top};
```

This will print `Warning` if you use either `-top` or `-notop` on the command line.  It will not print `Warning` if you do not use `-top` or `-notop`.